# Angular trying to add scope data to an array

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to add data from the Scope to an Array.
In my example I have `$scope.employee` which have several other fields, like name, number, email, etc.

So when I push the data to the Array I use:

```
array.push($scope.employee);
```

This works, because it adds the data to the array, but the binding still applies, so if I later on change thing in the scope, the data in the array also changes. I want this array to be static and not change. Just to hold the elements I have passed into it.
I would like to only add the data from the $scope.employee and not the binding.

I know it's possible to:

```
array.push({name: $employee.name, number: $employee.number});
```

But the `$scope.employee` have many fields, therefore I want to push the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `angular.copy` to make a deep copy without the pointers.

```
array.push(angular.copy($scope.employee));
```

[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)